# How to make a url whitelist function ? php

Tags: php

I want to make a whitelist that ignores all the unauthorized chars inputted on a webpage for example:

```
127.0.0.1/myweb/home.php?u=user // here is the authorized(default) url
```

but when an attacker(user of course) make my default url like this:

```
127.0.0.1/myweb/home.php/>"><script>alert("XSS")</script>&?u=user
```

and when the attacker press reload or enter to(reload the url with unauthorized codes) the malicious codes that reloaded from the page will be ignored and/or auto-delete or something. Then the reloaded page will return a safeurl like this:

```
127.0.0.1/myweb/home.php?u=user // back to the authorized url/s
```

**BUT** I do not have any code or knowledge to do this, I tried `preg_match()` to match if some codes *XSS type codes* exists on the url then it will redirect to an error page. But some says that it is not advisable because it is called `blacklisting` and the advisable is `whitelisting` . I do search of examples of whitelisting but I find nothing to what I am looking for . If I find nothing I need about whitelisting, I might continue to do a `preg_match()` *aka black listing* type of code

Addtional (error log apache)

*[Wed Jun 01 21:53:50.244776 2016] [core:error] [pid 3684:tid 1684] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 127.0.0.1:51833] AH00127: Cannot map GET /ooplr2/home.php/%3E%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22XSS%22)%3C/index.php HTTP/1.1 to file*

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: is it safe? I mean basically can prevent url xss attacks ? I read one of the posts in stackoverflow, it says there aren't that okay ? uhm, if my question will be solved by this function I will really use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is validation of input data. As you already mentioned it´s not save to rely on any user input so you should filter it. In which way this depends on your needs.

Easy way: `strip_tags()` -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Custom way: `regular expressions` -> http://regexr.com

Comment: This also depends in the way you work with the input data. Are they used in PHP or in sql statements? In case of sql you should take a look at `PDO` -> http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and prepared statements -> http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: in the custom way link you provided, on area that says: _Sample text for testing:_ if the chars detected on my webpage it will escape/ignore or somethhing ? Sorry, seems I do not get it.

Comment: I am using pdo, but my only problem is url xss attack type ?! whenever I type `/` after `home.php` my page gone broken _I dont even entered javascript type of tags_

Comment: any error messages? Have you checked your php/apache(?) logs?

Comment: I will post it on my question, Thanks

Comment: Uhm, the error only appears when i input a script like this: `/>"><script>alert("XSS")</script>&`

Comment: your webserver is trying to open a path that does not exist so the error occures. which webserver are you using? normally this would result in a html 404 error but this is no big deal. You may use htaccess for redirection of not existing files/folder. This post may help you -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608351/htaccess-redirect-from-subdirectory-to-root-directory-for-non-existing-files

Comment: I am using webserver, btw, where I can find .htaccess, Sorry and thanks

Comment: .htaccess (if you have one) is normally stored in the document root of your project . Which webserver are you using? apache, ngix,..? the shown behaviour is at least no error, it only shows you that the given URL does not exist on jyour server